# Freeze slide on external display (projecter), when using OpenOffice, and use laptop to do other (secret) thing

Tags: x11, kde, libreoffice, openoffice

I am running kde on debian jessie (X11+Gnu+Linux). When doing a presentation, using LibreOffice (OpenOffice) presenter, the audience sees the external display, and I see the presentation console on the internal display.

I then with to use the laptop to do some thing else, while continuing to display a slide for several minutes. I was hopping to freeze the external display, and do the other things on my laptop.

Is there a way to do this?, command line is good.
Other solutions specific to LibreOffice/OpenOffice, will also be accepted.

## Use Case

I am teaching a lesson to pupils. I have displayed a starter activity, and wish to do register, while they get on with this activity. They need to be able to refer back to this slide at any time during activity.

---

I have tried searching, but all I find is “help my xxx has frozen …”
I can not see anything in xrandr (and gui wrappers such as kscreen), am I missing something?

Comment: have you tried to use `Kscreen`?

Comment: I am not in the know of how your monitor setup is but can't you just switch between "extend desktop to 2nd monitor" (where two displays are operated independently) and "mirror desktop to 2nd monitor" (display the same thing on both monitors) settings ? I am not even sure if there is such settings on Debian. But since windoooze has it, well...

Comment: For my information, what happens exactly right now? Does the presentation, like, just vanish from the external display as soon as you remove focus from OpenOffice?

Comment: @calada I can press `esc` so that OpenOffice stops presenting, or I can not use computer for another task.

Comment: @MelBurslan can you elaborate, as not use if you have thought of something that I have not. Note that OpenOffice takes over both displays (when in extended mode) when presenting, one for audience, and is a presenter console.